# how to set home page in Godaddy file manager?

Tags: asp.net, web, hosting

I had successfully hosted my website on Go Daddy. When I typed my domain name in the address bar, I am getting "Maintenance" window. But when I append "/Home.aspx" to it, then it is successfully redirecting to the required home page. I want my domain name to represent the home page. What should I do?
Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `Home.aspx` as home page, then set web.config with following.

```
<system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />               
                <add value="Home.aspx"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

Or use `Global.aspx` , and in `Session_start` , set home page as following.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
        }
```